# error: redefinition of 'struct auditinfo_addr'

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "/usr/include/sys/queue.h"
#include "/usr/include/altq/altq_classq.h"
#include "/usr/include/altq/altq_rmclass.h"
#include "/usr/include/bsm/audit.h"
#include "/usr/include/sys/types.h"
#include "/usr/include/bsdxml_external.h"
#include "/usr/include/sys/bitstring.h"
#include "/usr/include/bsdxml.h"
#define offsetof(TYPE,MEMBER) ((int)(&((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER))
```

> audit.h this file include structure,for example au_tid.
>   those structure come from freebsd head file, compile and execute on freebsd system

```
struct au_tid {
    dev_t       port;
    u_int32_t   machine;
};
struct au_tid_addr {
    dev_t       at_port;
    u_int32_t   at_type;
    u_int32_t   at_addr[4];
};
struct au_mask {
    unsigned int    am_success;     
    unsigned int    am_failure;     
};
struct auditinfo {
    au_id_t     ai_auid;    
    au_mask_t   ai_mask;    
    au_tid_t    ai_termid;  
    au_asid_t   ai_asid;    
};
struct auditinfo_addr {
    au_id_t     ai_auid;    
    au_mask_t   ai_mask;    
    au_tid_addr_t   ai_termid;  
    au_asid_t   ai_asid;    
    au_asflgs_t ai_flags;   
};
struct auditpinfo {
    pid_t       ap_pid;     
    au_id_t     ap_auid;    
    au_mask_t   ap_mask;    
    au_tid_t    ap_termid;  
    au_asid_t   ap_asid;    
};
struct auditpinfo_addr {
    pid_t       ap_pid;     
    au_id_t     ap_auid;    
    au_mask_t   ap_mask;    
    au_tid_addr_t   ap_termid;  
    au_asid_t   ap_asid;    
    au_asflgs_t ap_flags;   
};
struct au_session {
    auditinfo_addr_t    *as_aia_p;  
    au_mask_t        as_mask;   
};
.......

int main()
{
    int temp =-1;
    temp = offsetof(struct  internal_state  ,  dummy);
    printf("%d\n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above code, there will be an error

> error:redefinition of ' >struct au_tid_addr '

prompts, but i can not solve the problem 
can anyone help me? Links to discussions on this problem are also highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where you got that header. but if you wrote it yourself, prefer `stddef.h` over defining your own `offsetoff`. The former is not dancing with UB.

Comment: You must have got the error message in a form "...previously defined in....", rings a bell?

Comment: What is the purpose of using the full absolute path in e.g. `#include "/usr/include/sys/queue.h"`? Why not simply `#include <sys/queue.h>`?

Comment: Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question to improve it, for example to copy (as text!) the *full* and *complete* output from the compiler, and paste it into the body of the question (without modifications).

Comment: Lastly, `offsetof` is a [standard C macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof). Don't define it yourself.

Comment: hmmm  yeah  i know include<stddef.h> definde offsetoff , but it's not problem,some structure come from Library functions in freebsd

Comment: sorry,this is my first time ask question

Comment: some like #include<sys/XXX.h>, it maybe can't find on freebsd, i need to designate it

Comment: like this                                                                                      
project.c:1063: warning: declaration does not declare anything
project.c:1064: error: redefinition of 'struct auditinfo'
project.c:1069: warning: declaration does not declare anything
project.c:1070: error: redefinition of 'struct auditinfo_addr'
project.c:1076: warning: declaration does not declare anything
project.c:1077: error: redefinition of 'struct auditpinfo'
project.c:1083: warning: declaration does not declare anything
project.c:1084: error: redefinition of 'struct auditpinfo_addr'

Comment: `sys/types.h` should be one of the first includes to include. The order of includes is important.